# Excel VBA not finding the cell wanted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that retrieves a data according to a search, for example, retrieving the adjacent cell of the one that contains "Date", but somehow excel doesn't match the result I'm looking for, I don't know if it's because that cell it's password protected. Here's my code:

```
SummarySheet.Range("C" & NRow).Value = WorkBk.Worksheets(2).Cells.Find("Fecha de ", After:=Range("I110")).Offset(0, 0)
```

And even when I tell excel it looks after I110, the first result is on Cell AU55.. (The offset 0,0 is intentional to see what is it finding)

Can Anyone Help.

Comment: You haven't specified which sheet the `After` is looking at, so it's using the currently active sheet.  Change to  `After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(2).Range("I110").....`.  Also, be careful of using `Worksheets(2)` - if you rearrange your sheets the second sheet will be different, so best use the sheet name.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
With WorkBk.Worksheets(2)
    SummarySheet.Range("C" & NRow).Value = .Cells.Find("Fecha de ", After:=.Range("I110"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, matchacse:=False).Offset(0, 0)
End With
```

and have:

- `Range("I110")` belong to the same workbook and worksheet of the `Cells` you're searching through
- all relevant `Find()` (`LookAt`, `LookIn`, ..) arguments explicitly specified, otherwise they would be assumed with their last setting even from Excel UI